# Angular js dynamic tags in template

Tags: templates, angularjs

```
var template ='<div id="'+'inst'+id+'" ng-click="setCurrentId('+id+')" >'+
        '< {{$scope.somevariable}} data-role="listview" >'+
        '<li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>'+
        '</{{$scope.somevariable}}>'+
        '</div>';
```

in the above code i want something like $scope.somevariable to be replaced  by ul or ol
but unfortunately this doesnt work

can someone tell me how to create dynamic tags using angular js?

Note: attributes like data-role maybe dynamic (i.e may or maynot exist).. so as such i cannot use ng-switch

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngSwitch` or `ngShow` directives to change content.

[ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)

[ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)